# Why is there a difference between same width for a table row vs grid?

Tags: html, css

I have an HTML table, and as it goes, its children have displays of `table-row` and `table-cell`. Some of the rows in it are styled as grid to better position the elements inside them.
This results in a little offsetting of the end-positioned elements as the widths of the rows gets uneven.

How do I mitigate this behaviour and keep the grid setting?

```css
table {
  border-collapse: collapse;
  width: 400px;
}
tr {
  border: 5px solid orange;
}
td {
  height: 50px;
}
tr.grid {
  border-color: green;
  display: grid;
}
```

```html
<table>
  <tr>
    <td></td>
  </tr>
  <tr class="grid">
    <td></td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: This seems like a hack and unexpected behavior, like you see, is almost inevitable. Why not do it properly? Leave the `<tr>` and `<td>` tags as they are and make a `<div>`, which is styled as a grid, inside the single `<td>` tag? You might even get away with styling the `<td>` tag as a grid and put, whatever you want in your grid, inside of that.

Comment: @KIKOSoftware Add multiple `<td>`s to a row, and them all respecting the grid dimensions together. That does not allow me to style a single `<td>` as a grid

Comment: I'm not sure you're getting what I am trying to say. A table row is a table row and it contains table cells. Right? So those are the `<tr>` and `<td>` tags. Now you want a grid inside your table. The only place to put a grid is inside a table cell. That table cell can be your whole row. So, to create a row with a grid in it you first use a normal row tag, inside it you place a cell tag, and inside of that the grid and its elements. You can probably use the cell tag as a grid, but all the grid elements have to be inside that single cell.

Comment: That means moving cells, that were previously next to that cell, inside the cell, so they can act as grid elements. Also, change the tags of them from `<td>` to `<div>`.

Comment: @KIKOSoftware  Cannot change a TD to a DIV since DIV is not allowed as a direct child of a TR.

Answer (score 0):

This happens to every display you give your `<tr>`. Weirdly enough this is how tables work. A workaround could be to add some css to your `.grid` class

```
tr.grid {
  width: calc(100% - 5px);
  margin-left: -3px;
}
```

This atleast fixes the snippet but could vary on your project itself.

Comment: This looks like a hack to correct for an hack. It still doesn't quite align when I zoom in, but I agree, it sort of works. I would prefer to display a table row as a table row. You correct for one weirdness now, but who knows what other problems could rear their nasty heads in the future? It is better to use things for the purpose they were made for.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest changing the markup to a set of div and spans and using CSS for the "table" display.  Style for tables has always been "fun" when you want to make it not use the default styles and markup.

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

table-container {
  display: table;
  border-collapse: collapse;
  width: 400px;
}

.table-row {
  border: 5px solid orange;
}

.table-row.grid {
  border-color: green;
  display: grid;
  grid-auto-flow: column;
  grid-template-rows: 50px;
}

.table-row span {
  display: inline-block;
  border: solid 1px blue;
}
```

```html
<div class="table-container">
  <div class="table-row">
    <span>&nbsp;</span><span>&nbsp;</span><span>&nbsp;</span>
  </div>
  <div class="table-row grid">
    <span>&nbsp;</span><span>&nbsp;</span><span>&nbsp;</span>
  </div>
</div>
```